# below android 11 sqflite is not working properly in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

Encountered SQLite query failures specifically on Huawei devices and Android versions below 11, despite utilizing the same SQLite version as other brands, resulting in SQFlite exceptions within the Flutter project.         [Image which occurs in my device of pixel 4 (Android 10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTr5j.png)

Give me a solution how to solve it